# how do i fix my script problem issuing SED command

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

i am trying to write my first script and everything is working fine it is to automatically install a new server, the only problem i have is using sed to change the ssl certificate file i have followed all the answers in the forums available here but i still cant get it to overwrite i have used 2 other sed commands and working fine

i am running script on ubuntu 16.04 with apache2 and php7.0 lamp
the script completes but no rewrite of conf

this is my script just in case anything is conflicting

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get -y update 
apt-get -y upgrade 
apt-get -y install apache2
apt-get install -y php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-mbstring php7.0-gd php7.0-intl php7.0-xml php7.0-mysql php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-zip
echo mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server/root_password password PASSWORD | debconf-set-selections
echo mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server/root_password_again password PASSWORD | debconf-set-selections
apt-get install -y mysql-server
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
a2enmod ssl
a2ensite default-ssl.conf
service apache2 restart
APP_PASS="PASSWORD"
ROOT_PASS="PASSWORD"
APP_DB_PASS="PASSWORD"
echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/dbconfig-install boolean true" | debconf-set-selections
echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/app-password-confirm password $APP_PASS" | debconf-set-selections
echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/admin-pass password $ROOT_PASS" | debconf-set-selections
echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/app-pass password $APP_DB_PASS" | debconf-set-selections
echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/reconfigure-webserver multiselect apache2" | debconf-set-selections
apt-get install -y phpmyadmin
sed -i 's/Port 22/Port 4747/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin yes/PermitRootLogin no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
service sshd restart
apt-get install vsftpd -y
sed -i 's/root/#root/g' /etc/ftpusers
service vsftpd restart
apt-get install software-properties-common -y
add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot -y
apt-get update -y
apt-get install python-certbot-apache -y
service apache2 stop
certbot certonly --standalone --non-interactive --agree-tos -m EMAIL@mymail.com -d domain.com
adduser --quiet --disabled-password --shell /bin/bash --home /home/USERNAME --gecos "User" USERNAME
echo "USERNAME:PASSWORD" | chpasswd
usermod -aG sudo USERNAME
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j DROP
crontab -l > mycron
echo "@daily letsencrypt renew --quiet && systemctl reload apache2" >> mycron
crontab mycron
rm mycron (WORKS BUT GIVES ERROR no crontab for root)
#sed -i "s|SSLCertificateFile=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem|SSLCertificateFile=/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem|g" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf (NOT WORKING)
#SSL_DEFAULT_CERT_PATH="SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem" 
#SSL_CERT_PATH="SSLCertificateFile /letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem"
#sed -i "s|.*\b$SSL_DEFAULT_CERT_PATH\b.*|$SSL_CERT_PATH|" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf (NOT WORKING)

service apache2 restart
```

these are the two i have tried but no luck

```
sed -i "s|SSLCertificateFile=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem|SSLCertificateFile=/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem|g" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf
```

does not work

```
SSL_DEFAULT_CERT_PATH="SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem" 
SSL_CERT_PATH="SSLCertificateFile /letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem"
sed -i "s|.*\b$SSL_DEFAULT_CERT_PATH\b.*|$SSL_CERT_PATH|" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf
```

does not work

original file SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
not sure if the spaces make a difference

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work, assuming the file contains the original string and you have write permission to the file.

Comment: here is the original file and it is writable as i am running the script as root SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem

Comment: Your first `sed` command is searching for a string which includes an equal sign and the original file doesn't have one. Your second `sed` command (with the variables set) works for me.

Comment: silly me thanks i got the first sed to work removing the = i have no ide but i could not get the second sed to work

Comment: It's extremely hard for us to help you debug "does not work", just like it'd be hard for your mechanic to diagnose your car trouble if you just told her your car "does not work". If you tell us in what way it "does not work" (wrong output, no output, core dump, error messages, something else?) there's a far greater chance of us being able to help you.

Comment: Is `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf`read-only? No idea what your problem is, so I think this is not the problem. Can you make a simplified copy of ` /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf` (only 2 lines?), post that file and the output when you use `sed` without `-i` ?